# MYSQL query with comma seperated field value into array

Tags: mysql, select

is there any way, i can get a field values (comma seperate) into an array or temporary table.

ex: i have field `following` with values `3,7,23,45`

i want get them into an array without using PHP, or into a temporary table.

as i need to do some joint queries based on those values.

any help is appreciated

thanks

my table name is: shoes
field name is following

sample table values are like these

```
   +----------+-----------+

   userId         following
   +----------+-----------+
    1            5,7,8,12
    2            5,2,1,67
```

now, when i search for userId 1, i want to get values `5,7,8,12` into an array or temp table.

Comment: http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/

Comment: Add your table structure with sample input output data

Comment: Thanks for that but i want to store them into an array/temp table
not to display on screen, because i need to do some more operations

Comment: Yes, but i need to do some more joint queries with this data,
So i want to get it done using mysql alone.

Comment: Not really sure if I understand your question clearly but I think it is better to handle that in the programming language you are using, if for instance you are using `PHP`, there is a function that splits the string and put them up into array. 

[**PHP Explode**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Comment: but now, i need to get those followers name etc from DB, which means i have to run through a loop, if i use PHP
but if i do using mysql, i can do some join queries to achieve this

Comment: Try my solution below. It will do the job and you can use the results to do joins against other tables. Or better, use it to split the values off into a separate table as a one off job.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible although not particularly quick. The best solution is to redesign the database to move the comma separated list into a different table, with one row for each comma separated element.

However if you want an SQL way to do it then something like the following will do it (this relies on having a table called integers with a single column called i, with 10 rows with the values 0 to 9).

```
SELECT DISTINCT shoes.userId , substring_index(substring_index(shoes.FollowingIdString, ',', anInt), ',', -1) AS SplitField
FROM shoes,
(SELECT a.i+b.i*10+c.i*100 AS anInt
FROM integers a, integers b, integers c) Sub1
HAVING SplitField IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming* you have a table PersonList which has multiple columns and this is the table where you want to join to get the name of the followers list. eg

PersonTable

```
ID   Name
1    AAA
2    BBB
```

there is a mysql function called [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set), eg

```
SELECT a.userID, GROUP_CONCAT(b.Name)
FROM   Follower a
       INNER JOIN Person b
        ON FIND_IN_SET(b.id, a.following) > 0
GROUP BY a.userID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d3052/2)